# TortoiseGit - how to see what's different?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-diff

I regularly commit work in my local box in order to pull changes from origin and I'm now at a point that I want to evaluate whether to push my changes up or not.  I know there are files I want to push because the browser access shows old text in them, but I don't want to break something else.

How can I show what's in my committed local repo that will change the remote repo when I push it - in TortoiseGit, not cmd line.  I keep trying to use the TortoiseGit/Show Log command but it's a huge mass of data that makes no sense given the purpose, but maybe I'm just not reading it correctly.

Comment: Using Linux so I don't have TortoiseGit but in the meantime you can use **git cherry -v**

Comment: This returns nothing. I am trying to see differences between committed changes, one set in remote, one set in local.

Comment: Then that means there's no difference between your local and remote repos, they're in the same state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds as if the Sync dialog is what you are looking for.

The SyncDialog shows the commits and diffs which will be pushed and which were pulled:

[image: SyncDialog]